# Parallel compilation linux real time kernel

Tags: pi-3, linux, kernel, cross-compilation

Within the framework of a lab I had to compile a kernel using several commands such as:
make zImage j-8
make modules j-8
make dtbs j-8

j-8 means I used parallel compilation but I am asked this question:
how can we know if a parallel compilation is complete without errors ? 
I don’t know if the answer is the simple fact that the shell completed successfully (the exit status is zero) and that I can write a command in a new line or if the answer is more complicated.

Comment: `make` prints an error message in case of failures, something like `make: *** [target] Error message`. You can also check the exit code: 0 means success, 1 means the target is outdated, 2 means error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dmitry points out, errors produced during `make` should be obvious.

However, it's not impossible, when running a parallel build, for one task to fail and the error output to get buried by output from concurrent tasks.  *Remaining* tasks [will then be aborted](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html), but I'm not sure that this in itself is indicated.

You can use [`-O` or `-Oline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html#Parallel-Output) to make concurrent output more orderly, but when in doubt, scroll up if possible.